# Node print [Circular] in console

Tags: node.js, circular-reference

I am studying data structures, doubly linked list, right now. I would like to see my .prev property, but it keeps just printing [Circular] is there a way to go around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone just started studying data structures like me and went came across this problem. [Circular] simply means that it's pointing to the node that points to the other node that points to this node.

So somthing like:

NodeA.next = NodeB
NodeB.prev = NodeA

since the relationship is circular, meaning, they point to each other. That's why we just get [Circular] instead of the whole node printed.